# How to use Python etree objects as additional input documents for XSLT

Tags: python, xslt, lxml

Using Python's `lxml.etree` module I want to refer to an additional input document in a stylesheet like this

```
<xsl:copy-of select="document($abc)//order"/>
```

where `$abc` is an XML document that I already have as an `etree.Element` object in my code.  I know how to refer to a file document, but I would like to use the (parsed) XML object directly, without having to serialize it as an extra step (and having XSLT parse it again).

Is this possible?  If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to find a way to pass an element as a parameter but I have not found one. What has worked for me is setting up an [extension function](http://lxml.de/extensions.html#xpath-extension-functions) that simply returns the element:

```
from lxml import etree

sheet = etree.XML('''\
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf" exclude-result-prefixes="mf">
  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:copy-of select="foo[bar = mf:node_set()/item/bar]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
''')

doc1 = etree.XML('''\
<root>
  <foo>
    <bar>a</bar>
  </foo>
  <foo>
    <bar>b</bar>
  </foo>
  <foo>
    <bar>c</bar>
  </foo>
</root>''')

doc2 = etree.XML('''\
<items>
  <item>
    <bar>a</bar>
  </item>
  <item>
    <bar>c</bar>
  </item>
</items>''')

def node_set(context, node):
    return node

ns = etree.FunctionNamespace('http://example.com/mf')
ns.prefix = "mf"
ns['node_set'] = lambda _: doc2


transformer = etree.XSLT(sheet)

result = transformer(doc1)
print(str(result))
```

Output is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root><foo>
    <bar>a</bar>
  </foo><foo>
    <bar>c</bar>
  </foo></root>
```

You can then change the function as needed with e.g.

```
ns['node_set'] = lambda _: etree.XML('<items><item><bar>b</bar></item></items>')

result = transformer(doc1)
print(str(result))
```

and get

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root><foo>
    <bar>b</bar>
  </foo></root>
```

Of course using an extension function opens up different data representation strategies, here is an example that instead puts the additional documents into a list and then uses an extension function taking the index into a list to select a document:

```
from lxml import etree

sheet = etree.XML('''\
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf" exclude-result-prefixes="mf">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <example nr="1">
         <xsl:copy-of select="foo[bar = mf:get_doc(1)/item/bar]"/>
      </example>
      <example nr="2">
         <xsl:copy-of select="foo[bar = mf:get_doc(2)/item/bar]"/>
      </example>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
''')

doc1 = etree.XML('''\
<root>
  <foo>
    <bar>a</bar>
  </foo>
  <foo>
    <bar>b</bar>
  </foo>
  <foo>
    <bar>c</bar>
  </foo>
</root>''')

doc2 = etree.XML('''\
<items>
  <item>
    <bar>a</bar>
  </item>
  <item>
    <bar>c</bar>
  </item>
</items>''')

doc3 = etree.XML('<items><item><bar>b</bar></item></items>')

param_docs = [doc2, doc3]

def get_doc(context, a):
    return param_docs[int(a) - 1]

ns = etree.FunctionNamespace('http://example.com/mf')
ns.prefix = "mf"
ns['get_doc'] = get_doc


transformer = etree.XSLT(sheet)

result = transformer(doc1)
print(str(result))
```

Here is the output:

```
<root>
  <example nr="1">
    <foo>
    <bar>a</bar>
  </foo>
    <foo>
    <bar>c</bar>
  </foo>
  </example>
  <example nr="2">
    <foo>
    <bar>b</bar>
  </foo>
  </example>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion.  I have used Python extension functions before, but didn't think of this way to pass a node(set).  I tested it and it works fine in my situation.  Measuring performance of a large number of operations on small XML documents shows that it is more than 3 times faster to use these Python extensions than to write a temporary file and use the plain document() function.

Comment: Glad it is working fine for you. I also tried setting up a custom resolver http://lxml.de/resolvers.html#uri-resolvers as shown in the lxml docs, in the hope that would allow us to use e.g. `document("my-docs:1")` and in the resolver then return an etree object but somehow I always ended up getting error that an `_InputDocument` and not an `_Element` was required to be returned. Perhaps someone with more insight into the lxml architecture can tell whether there is some way to use a resolver and return an etree object.

Comment: This is the way I looked at first and I now doubt this is possible.  The resolver helper functions `resolve_*` all return some parseable XML, either a string or a file.  An alternative is to serialize your XML to a string and then use `resolve_string` (in your own resolver), as you probably already know, but this takes one redundant serialize/parse step.